# Fibonacci : demonstration by induction : $\phi^{n-2} \leq F_n \leq \phi^{n-1} $

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

Fibonacci  Number :

> I try to demonstrate that
> $\phi^{n-2} \leq  F_n \leq \phi^{n-1} $  where  $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$

> I started  by    having  :
> $\phi^{n-3} \leq  F_{n-1} \leq \phi^{n-2} $.
> Then  : $\phi^{n-2} +\phi^{n-3} \leq  F_{n+1}\leq \phi^{n-1} +\phi^{n-2} $

$\phi^{n-3}(\phi +1) \leq  F_{n+1}\leq \phi^{n-2}(\phi +1)$

and here I did know how to conclude for  $F_{n+1}$

Comment: Use the fact that $\phi + 1 = \phi^2$. Also you need to use two induction hypotheses, with two base cases; or a strong induction, with two base cases.

Comment: I suppose  her  that   p(n ) is True   and  p(n-1) is True  too.   But how can I simplify and get rid of $\Large \phi^2$  Once I get   the inequalities :   $\Large \phi^{n-3} \phi^2 \leq  F_{n+1}\leq \phi^{n-2}\phi^2$.

Comment: Got it , thanks  you it's  Obvious,

Comment: Don't use `\large` indiscriminately, and remember to end math equations with a `$` as well. $P(n)$ is true does not imply $P(n-1)$ is also true, unless you are using strong/complete induction, where they are both true. Remember to write the base cases.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\phi + 1 = \phi^2$,
$$\phi^{n-3}(\phi +1) \leq  F_{n+1}\leq \phi^{n-2}(\phi +1)$$
is equivalent to
$$\phi^{n-3} \phi^2 \leq  F_{n+1}\leq \phi^{n-2}\phi^2$$
which simplifies to
$$\phi^{n-1} \leq  F_{n+1}\leq \phi^{n}$$
as required.

Comment: CW because the question was answered in the comments.